# Fail to run a .NET 2.0 application with mono 2.6.7

Tags: windows, mono

- Update: After installing mono-complete, there are some warnings:

  ```
  $ mono HandyOutliner.exe 
  libpng warning: Incorrect sBIT chunk length

  ** (HandyOutliner.exe:18066): WARNING **: GdipSetPenCustomStartCap isn't implemented

  ** (HandyOutliner.exe:18066): WARNING **: GdipSetPenCustomEndCap isn't implemented
  ```

Also when I try to open the application's samples/sample_toc_1.txt in the bookmark source box, there is an error reported "ole32.dll", which seems to be missing.

I wonder if we can do something to fix them?

**Original:** I am trying to run handyoutlinerfo (downloadable from http://handyoutlinerfo.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu 10.10, but not succeed. I was wondering if there are some suggestions here?

The software's system requirements are:

```
OS: Win32 NT/XP/7  
Platform:   .NET Framework 2.0 or above
```

My mono version is

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-3ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
```

The output error of opening the software in mono is

```
$ mono HandyOutliner.exe

** (HandyOutliner.exe:12318): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /home/tim/Desktop/HandyOutliner_1.1.4.0_bin/HandyOutliner.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Windows.Forms    (assemblyref_index=0)
     Version:    2.0.0.0
     Public Key: b77a5c561934e089
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/home/tim/Desktop/HandyOutliner_1.1.4.0_bin/).


** (HandyOutliner.exe:12318): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

** (HandyOutliner.exe:12318): WARNING **: Missing method EnableVisualStyles in assembly /home/tim/Desktop/HandyOutliner_1.1.4.0_bin/HandyOutliner.exe, type System.Windows.Forms.Application

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Comment: very strange - on natty it has the same mono version - this application starts OK.

Comment: I was wondering what files are needed to install mono? I might have missed some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the program for Linux and Mac OS X. Please download the latest version from the [project page](http://handyoutlinerfo.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It works! Thanks! When running `$ mono HandyOutliner.exe `, I got two warnings :"


    ** (HandyOutliner.exe:4629): WARNING **: GdipSetPenCustomStartCap isn't implemented

    ** (HandyOutliner.exe:4629): WARNING **: GdipSetPenCustomEndCap isn't implemented


" Does it matter?

Comment: I'm also getting the same message. This is a debug message inside Mono, not a error.

Answer (score 6):

The application is looking for the 'System.Windows.Forms' assembly, which is in the package [libmono-winforms2.0-cil](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libmono-winforms2.0-cil).

If you want to install all of mono & its dependencies, you can install [mono-complete](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mono-complete).

Comment: Thanks! It works. But now I have some new warnings and errors. Can we fix them?

Comment: Update for 16.04: Use [libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil) Source of the information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10696/54675

Answer (score 2):

HandyOutliner will only work properly on Windows. This program uses Windows-specific functions through P/Invoke. (Detecting text encoding). These functions are not supported in Linux.

I will try to adapt the project for Linux / Mono. Thank you for your feedback.